# What is generative and discriminative model? How are they used in Natural Language Processing?

Tags: nlp, language-model

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879432/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generative-and-discriminative-algorithm) asks about generative vs. discriminative algorithm, but can someone give an example of the difference between these forms when applied to Natural Language Processing? **How are generative and discriminative models used in NLP?**

Comment: @knb The link to the video is broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you are predicting the topic of a document given its words.

A generative model describes how likely each topic is, and how likely words are given the topic. This is how it says documents are actually "generated" by the world -- a topic arises according to some distribution, words arise because of the topic, you have a document. Classifying documents of words W into topic T is a matter of maximizing the joint likelihood: P(T,W) = P(W|T)P(T)

A discriminative model operates by only describing how likely a topic is given the words. It says nothing about how likely the words or topic are by themselves. The task is to model P(T|W) directly and find the T that maximizes this. These approaches do not care about P(T) or P(W) directly.